# Hiding factory implementations

Tags: java, abstract-factory

In my application I have defined four interfaces, say `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Depending on a compile-time setting, I'd like to use different implementations of these interfaces. I defined an abstract factory `Factory` like so:

```
package app.core;

abstract class Factory {
    public abstract A getA();
    public abstract B getB();
    public abstract C getC();
    public abstract D getD();
}
```

and two implementations that return different implementations of interfaces `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`; each set in a different package:

```
package app.core.monolithic;

class MonoA implements A { ... } // and so on for B, C and D

class MonolithicFactory extends Factory {
    /* implementations of getters */
}

package app.core.modular;

class ModularA implements A { ... } // and so on for B, C and D

class ModularFactory extends Factory {
    /* implementations of getters */
}
```

How can I prevent access to the factory implementations? I can just keep the implementations of the interfaces package-private, but if I do the same with the factory implementations, the code that determines the implementation to use cannot instantiate any concreete factory, because it sits in `app.core`.

I have been banging my head against my desk for a few hours now, so I may be missing something obvious. It seems to me that this is only achievable with reflection, unless I keep everything in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

Define the  factory implementations as `private static` classes of a public class that returns instances of these factories.
The clients will retrieve factory instances from this public class.
In this way only the factory interface can be referenced by the clients of the factory.
Note that you should introduce an interface for the `Factory`because Clients should not need to know the existence of the abstract class.

Another alternative is providing two packaging : an API and an implementation JAR.
Clients should depend on the API jar at compile time and depend on both API and implementation JARs at runtime.
Many libraries work in this way to do the separation between internal an API.

Comment: Wouldn't all interface implementations (`MonolithicA`, `ModularA` and so on) have to be in the same package as the public class, if they are to be hidden too?

Comment: II you want to "hide" them, they should not be public (first way) or in the API part (alternative way).

Comment: Neither the factories nor the implementations are public. Ideally I'd like to keep everything package private, but then the public class cannot create any factory implementation.